# 'ProductModuleName-Swift.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use my protocol method of swift class into objective-c class for it I have to import 'ProductModuleName-Swift.h' and declare its protocol in interface but it shows error: 'ProductModuleName-Swift.h' file not found.

But when I import it into test.m file then its fine but when I import it into test.h then it shows the error.

example:

test.h

```
#import "myProject-Swift.h"

@interface test : UIViewController<mySwiftDelegate>
```

or There is any way to use protocol method of swift in obj-c class

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if `myProject` is the **Module Name**, not the project name.

Comment: yes it is my product module name I already confirms it from buildSetting->packaging

Comment: Did you forget to use @objc on all your swift classes?

Comment: You should stick to Apple's convention and use capitalized type names. This will avoid confusion when asking questions too.

Comment: @Schemetrical here is my code - 

objc protocol mySwiftDelegate {
    
    objc optional func myDelegateMethod( )
}

Comment: assume ' @ ' already include before both 'objc' in previous comment

Comment: already did it but no effect.

the main issue I guess it that why #import "myProject-Swift.h" is not working in test.h file and it is working in test.m file

Answer (score 1):

Go to Targets -> Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code Generation and make sure the "Objective-C Bridging Header" points to the correct place and the "Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name" is the correct file. My header name for the unit tests defaulted to Module-NameTest-swift.h I needed to remove "Test" from the title.